# Unit Testing Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core - Populating Tag Public Properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Trying to implement best practices on a new project, I figured I'd see how far I can extend unit testing to the MVC Tag Helpers. In this instance, I have a very simple helper taken from the Tag Helper section of the [MVC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring), so now I have `<email mail-to="Support"></email>`.

The actual code for this is below.

```
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string EmailDomain = "contoso.com";

    public string MailTo { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext ctx, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";
        var addr = $"{MailTo}@{EmailDomain}";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", $"mailto:{addr}");
        output.Content.SetContent(addr);
    }
}
```

The resulting HTML is as expected and if I set a breakpoint when running the code I can see that the pascal-case `mail-to` is correctly populating the camel-case `MailTo` inside the C# class.

Now I have the following unit test:

```
[TestMethod]        
public void EmailTagHelper_GeneratesExpectedHtml()
{
    var emailHelper = new EmailTagHelper();

    var ctx = new TagHelperContext(new TagHelperAttributeList
    {
        {"mail-to", "Support"}
    }, new Dictionary<object, object>(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

    var output = new TagHelperOutput("email",
        new TagHelperAttributeList(), (useCachedResult, htmlEncoder) =>
        {
            var tagHelperContent = new DefaultTagHelperContent();
            tagHelperContent.SetContent(string.Empty);
            return Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(tagHelperContent);
        });

    emailHelper.Process(ctx, output);
    Assert.AreEqual("a", output.TagName);
    Assert.AreEqual("mailto:Support@contoso.com", output.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

The first assert is passing and if I breakpoint inside the tag helper class I can see that the attributes are matching those that are passed when running the application normally, but for some reason the mapping of pascal to camel case `MailTo` is not occurring during testing.

I am basing my work on the source code of the [MVC Tag Helper Unit Tests](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test) as found on Github but I think I am missing something.

Any advice or am I going to have to set `emailHelper.MailTo` in my test, which in all honesty seems like a bit of a cop out answer if so :( Hoping it's just a nuance I am overlooking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you did not set the property on the system under test.

ie

```
emailHelper.MialTo = "Support";
```

which means this line of code

```
var addr = $"{MailTo}@{EmailDomain}";
```

wont generate the expected email address if `MailTo` is blank when processing.

No where in your code custom implementation do you access the context so stands to reason that unless you actually set the `MailTo` property, it wont have a value when `Process` is called in the unit test.

The framework would have interpreted the razor and populate the property for you when running in live code but that is not the case in a unit test.

Comment: This was my suspicion, that Razor was somehow getting involved and doing the mapping before the Tag Helper was actually allowed to run....a  little annoying they've done that IMO but I can see why they have done it. I will have to see if I can find how this is happening and maybe implement a test version.

All the same, thanks for the input! Was working along the right lines at least :)

Comment: I had perhaps thought that calling `emailHelper.Init(ctx)` might handle this but it seems it's handled outside this TagHelper class entirely; somehow.

Comment: @JakHammond Yes it is, I would suggest reviewing their tests that you linked in the OP. I'm noticing that they may be creating a view context and assigning it to the helper to do what you desired. check this test https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test/TextAreaTagHelperTest.cs#L150